# Can an F# query expression filter for items that are NOT in a sub-query?

Tags: f#

I have the following sample that finds the numbers in s1 that are not in s2.

```ml
let s1 = seq { 1..3 }
let s2 = seq { 3..4 }

s1
|> Seq.filter (fun x -> s2 |> Seq.forall (fun y -> x <> y))
|> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn $"{x}")
```

This prints 1 and 2 as expected.

Can this also be expressed as a query expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a fairly elegant way to do so.

```ml
open System.Linq.Expressions

let s1 = seq { 1..3 }
let s2 = seq { 3..4 }

let query1 = query {
  for x in s1 |> Seq.except s2 do
  select x
}

Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn $"{x}") query1
```

Comment: If I add the print statement to review the output it lists 1,2,3. This is a great starting point though. Maybe this can work with some tweaks. I'll what I can do with it.

Comment: It won't compile with not exists. I guess that's not a thing in query expressions :-(

Comment: yeah, working on it. I do C# mostly, I thought linq would be similar between the languages

Comment: Very nice! That's an interesting version. Now the query expression  can be dropped completely with `s1 |> Seq.except s2  |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn $"{x}")`

Comment: Using `Seq.except` to do this is a very nice trick (and the way to go). I did not realize this is in the standard library!

Comment: one issue with Seq.except, it iterates the entire left side to compute the set difference between the two, so it will run forever with an infinite sequence on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I think your existing solution using `filter` and `forall` is perfectly fine and does not need to be converted to query expressions - those are great for SQL-like queries and querying databases, but I think they are often a bit unhelpful for basic sequence processing.

To answer your question, you can do this using a nested `query` (as in the answer from Violet), but using the `all` operation:

```
query { 
  for x in s1 do
  where (query { for y in s2 do all (y > 0) })
  select x }
```

This is really exactly the same as your original code - the outer query implements `filter` and the nested query implements `forall`. You could also freely combine the two:

```
query { 
  for x in s1 do
  where (Seq.forall (fun y -> x <> y) s2)
  select x }
```

Although I guess it gets a bit nicer if you turn `s2` into a set first:

```
let s2set = set s2 

query { 
  for x in s1 do
  where (not (s2set.Contains x))
  select x }
```

Comment: I see what you mean. It's possible but not really advantageous. The query expression versions aren't any simpler to grasp than the original.